# Converting R named array to Python

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am in the process of converting an R package to Python. In the package they use a named array as a kind of lookup table to get precomputed values depending on user defined parameters:

```
ar <- array(data     = 1:27,
            dim      = c(3, 3, 3),
            dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c"),
                            c("1", "2", "3"),
                            c("x", "y", "z")))

param1 <- "a"
param2 <- 1.5
param3 <- "z"
ar[param1, ,param3]
```

They then also use the `dimnames` of the second dimension to linearly interpolate the user parameter `param2`.

My question would be how to best convert this data structure to Python? I am thinking that a structured numpy array would work in theory, however I didn't find a good way to convert the R array to this type.

I tried using `reticulate` to export it. This worked in so far, as that it saved the array, however it dropped the names.

```
library(reticulate)
np = import("numpy")
np$save("test.npy",r_to_py(ar))
```

Comment: Wouldn't a dict be the next best approximation of a named list in R?

Comment: Yes if I can convert the named array to a named list, that would also work. So ultimately I'm looking for a good way to convert it

Comment: this is probably the resource you are looking for: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/#type-conversions